# Tornado Coroutine fails with 'dict' object not callabale

Tags: python-asyncio, tornado

Python version: 3.6

I am not super expert in Python, I was trying to use Tornado to implement a simple REST server and use non blocking coroutine to call a blocking function. When I return Json from the blocking function it fails with *TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable*
Here's the code

```
@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    jsonResponse = yield self.process_request(imageBytes)
    self.write(json.dumps(jsonResponse))

@gen.coroutine
def process_request(self, imageBytes):
    response = yield (executor.submit(self.test_func(), None))
    return response

def test_func(self):
    print('test func')
    time.sleep(1)
    jsonDataSet = {"text": "hello 123"}
    return jsonDataSet
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, followed the sample code from Tornado reference. Any pointers will be helpful?

Latest:
I moved to async & await now I am getting *"Object of type 'coroutine' is not JSON serializable"*

```
async def test_func():
    print('test func')
    time.sleep(1)
    jsonDataSet = {"text": "hello 123"}
    return jsonDataSet
    #return "test"
response = await `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, test_func)`
```

Comment: You are calling `self.test_func()` instead of passing it as callable to the executor. That's why a dict (´jsonDataSet`) is passed to the executor that tries to call it.

Comment: Corrected it, but now it doesn't recognize test_func

Comment: I made the function global outside the class and it is the same error. 'dict' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

`executor.submit()` requires a callable, but you're already calling the `test_func` function. When you call `test_func()`, you're essentially passing its return value (which is a dict) to the `submit()` function.

You need pass this function without calling:

```
executor.submit(self.test_func, None)
```

---

> Latest: I moved to async & await now I am getting "Object of type 'coroutine' is not JSON serializable"

`run_in_executor` is for running a normal function in a separate thread. It's not meant for running coroutines.

What's happening here is `run_in_executor` is calling `test_func()` coroutine, which automatically returns an awaitable object (because it's a coroutine).

If you want to execute `test_func` using `run_in_executor`, just make it a normal function (don't use `async def`).